# Watching a file and sending an email when it changes

Tags: email, watch

I have a log file that occasionally has critical errors.  Each time a critical error occurs, I'd like to have an email sent to myself notifying me of the change.  Is there a unix tool / set of unix tools I can adapt for this purpose?

What I thought of doing was

```
tail -f logfile | grep CRITICAL > critical.errors
watch tail critical.errors   # And somehow, email on changes.
```

However, the watch command doesn't take an action.  So ... is there something like 'watch' that does.  Or perhaps a good existing script that will do this?  I can homebrew a bash/python solution, but I'd rather reuse existing tools for cleaner error handling, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try IWatch - it's a perl script based on inotify that does just what you need:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/iwatch/

You can also roll your own with [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/), in particular `inotifywait`. Modifying example #2 from that page (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh
file=logfile
cp $file $file.last
while true; do
  EVENT=$(inotifywait --format '%e' $file)
  [ $? != 0 ] && exit
  [ "$EVENT" = "MODIFY" ] && ( diff $file $file.last | mail ... ) && cp $file $file.last
done
```

You could also keep a byte/line counter and only mail the new bytes/lines, but using diff is simpler. It could cause performance issues if the file gets big and changes constantly though.

Comment: Is there something like this for Windows?